# Can limits to (positive) infinity be replaced by ordinals?

Tags: ordinals

For example, does the following hold?

$$\left(1+\frac1\omega\right)^\omega=e$$

Comment: What is $1/\omega$?

Comment: From my (overly simplified and limited) understanding: $$\frac1\omega=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$$

Comment: @KennyLau No, $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=0$, *unless* you're working in nonstandard analysis.

Comment: @egreg: Even in nonstandard analysis, isn't $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n$ just zero? But yes, to make sense of this question one would have to interpret $\omega$ as a hyperreal or surreal number (or something like that).

Comment: What might interest you though is the concept of [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis). If $\omega$ denotes any positive transfinite hyperreal number, then $$\left(1+\frac{1}{\omega}\right)^\omega =e - \epsilon$$ for an appropriate *infinitesimal* number $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $\left(1+\frac{1}{\omega}\right)^{\omega}$ doesn't make any sense, since there is no division by ordinals or raising a real to ordinal power. However, there is a way this *can* be made a formal statement.

A sequence of elements of $X$ is just a function $f: \omega \rightarrow X$. Now, consider $\omega +1$ with order topology: here, the point $\omega$ is the limit of the sequence $\{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$ of all natural numbers. So, a sequence $f:\omega\rightarrow X$ has a limit iff the function $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $g:\omega+1\rightarrow X$: the limit will be $g(\omega)$.

Now, consider a function $f: \omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: $f(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. As we know, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)=e$. So, this function can be extended to a function $g:\omega+1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(n)=f(n)$ for $n \in \omega$ and $g(\omega)=e$.

Comment: FYI, Borel made use of ordinals (including ordinal arithmetic) to describe growth rates of certain functions (among other places, see his 1901 paper [*Sur les ordres d'infinitude*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5vE7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA154)), but this is not really relevant to Kenny Lau's question.

Answer (score 1):

No. $(1 + \frac{1}{x})^x $ represents an intangible expression. $x$ can take any value and by calculating it, it will not give you $e$. It's the series from $0$ to $\infty $ or the $\lim{x \to \infty}$ that gives you $e$.